# No export syncblk found

Tags: windbg, sos

I am getting message as No export syncblk found while uysing WinDbg

```
!syncblk
No export syncblk found
```

Below commands are working successfully-

```
 .loadby sos clr
 .load c:\sos\sos.dll
 !analyze -v
 !threads
 !clrstack -a
```

Comment: Why would you load 2 different SOS extensions?

Comment: Try .chain command to see what extensions are loaded. Also try it with original casing !SyncBlk.

Comment: I have not loaded 2 extensions. Ignore above snapshot. I have loaded only SOS.DLL

Comment: 0:000> !SyncBlk
Error requesting SyncBlk data